# How do you get back to the "normal" view

Tags: support, status-bydesign

So when you first enter the main site you get the following ...

showing top questions:
[image]

but once you've clicked on the "questions" button you get this ...

[image]

even clicking the "active tab doesn't get you back to the "Top questions" .

How does one get back to the top questions? or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind ....

I found it.  You simply click on the "Electrical Engineering" LED bar.

[image]